# Create pointer to a custom class (created by myself)

Tags: c#, class, pointers

The code is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MazeGen
{
    unsafe class Node
    {
       bool visited = false;
       int linksNumber = 0;
       Node*[] links;
       public Node(Node* n)
       {
          visited = true;
          linksNumber++;
          links[0] = n;
       }
    }
}
```

The error of Visual Studio is the following:

> Error CS0208: Can not take the address of a managed type
>   ('MazeGen.Node'),
>       get the size of, or declare a pointer to it

I have the same Error in at row 16 and column 21, when I pass `(Node* n)` to the constructor

How can I declare a single dimension array of pointers to an object of type `MazeGen.Node` ?

Thank you vary much for your time.

Comment: Just a side note, you should probably not write unmanaged code unless you have a really good reason to do so. I'm not saying you don't but a warning is appropriate.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: I think the key misunderstanding is that you don't understand that reference types like `Node` are always heap-allocated and references act like pointers in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes in C# are entirely managed by the CLR, their memory allocation, pointers and so on. They're not designed directly to be used as pointers.

When you declare a variable of a class type, under the hood, that's in fact a pointer (sort of), since you really hold a reference to the data, which really lives in the heap, you always pass that reference around in method arguments, but it's just passing a pointer to the same piece of data. That's why classes are called "reference types".

Contrary to that, variables of any struct type are stored right where you declare it, you have the data itself, not a reference to something else. They live on the stack for local variables and just as part of the object in the heap when they're fields of classes. The CLR allows to use and pass pointers to structs, provided you declare the containing body as `unsafe`, and work much like C++ does.

Normally, using `unsafe` is recommended only when interacting with unmanaged code that uses pointers, as you lose the memory management features of .NET and its type safety if you're not careful about it. Moreover, in your program, unless there is more to it than the posted snippet, there is no reason to use it, as normal .NET classes can achieve the same result quite easily:

```
public class Node
{
   public bool Visited {get; set;}
   public int LinksNumber {get; set;}
   IList<Node> Links {get; private set;}

   public Node(Node n)
   {
      Visited = true;
      LinksNumber = 1;
      Links = new List<Node>() {n};
   }
}
```

This achieves the same result (seems pretty much a tree-like structure), but using the built-in `List<T>` class to hold the references to linked nodes. Since Node is a refence type (because it's a `class`) the list will hold an automatically managed array of references to the extra nodes.